# I can't submit my app to appstore due to icon error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I prepared everything to my app to be submitted to the app-store. I have add all the icons required and i created bundle id and everything is ready to go.

Whenever i validate my app, and i click submit to the app-store I'm getting two errors you can see them in the screenshot below now almost three hours i could not figure out what is the problem since this is my first app to be submitted to the app-store any help please?[image]

Comment: Make sure they are in your images.xcassets and check the size at the attributes inspector on the right of the screen. Sometimes it adds the wrong size image to the wrong asset.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to delete all icon images from your project and then insert them again a second time. Seems like `xCode` has a problem with the reference to your icons.

Furthermore you should check your `images.xcassets` folder where all `AppIcons` will be inserted. You should be sure to insert the correct picture with the correct size in the right place. Sometimes xCode lets you insert wrong pictures too but will produce a warning instead of marking the wrong in the asset screen.

Comment: i did as he told me, i could not look one by one that will make your brain destroyed. Anyway i delete them all and i inserted them again with different names and that worked

Comment: Nice! I had several times problems with adding the app icons, maybe i did something wrong with the naming too... not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add 2 icons

60*60 and 120*120

in png format than select clear and create archive.

Comment: i add them all my friend, and they are all in png

Comment: Add images in images.xcassets

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct images in to your project and be sure to check the 'copy if needed' option when your first add them. To me, it looks like you have added them in without copying them to your project and you have either moved them or deleted them outside of Xcode.